# Sum of two datas using computed on Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to add my netgain + drawdown computed data, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do it. Can anyone help me please? Basically, I'd just like to total my net gain and drawdown e.g: 10 + -4 or something like that.

Here are my codes below:

```html
<td> {{ netgain + drawdown }} </td>
```

```js
  computed: {
    totals () {
      if (! this.zones[0]) {
        return [];
      }

      return this.zones[0].cycles.map(cycle => {
        return {
          netgain: this.cycleComputation('netgain', cycle.trades),
          drawdown: this.cycleComputation('drawdown', cycle.trades)
        }
      });
    },

methods: {
    cycleComputation (calculate, trades) {
      if (! trades.length) {
        return 0;
      }

      if (calculate === 'netgain') {
        const ups = trades.filter(trade => parseFloat(trade.realizedPL) > 0);

        if (ups.length) {
          return ups.map(net => parseFloat(net.realizedPL)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }

      if (calculate === 'drawdown') {
        const downs = trades.filter(trade => parseFloat(trade.realizedPL) < 0);

        if (downs.length) {
          return downs.map(net => parseFloat(net.realizedPL)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }
    },

    total (type) {
      if (! this.totals.length) {
        return 0;
      }

      if (this.totals.length === 1) {
        return this.totals[0][type];
      }

      return this.totals.reduce((a, b) => a[type] + b[type]);
    },
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're returning an array from `totals`? Are you looking to add all of the values from the array or what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add the values of arrays from drawdown and netgains. I have a code wherein I fetch datas that has "realizedPL" object and I'm trying to sum all the realizedPL that are getting pulled out

Comment: why do you put functions with args like this `cycleComputation(calculate, trades)` in the computed dict, methods should go to the methods dict.

Comment: hi, sorry if the code is confusing but the `cycleComputation` isn't inside the computed dict. edited my post for it to be seen better. thanks!